# Connecting to the google ads API with coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016, google-ads-api

I need to connect to the google ads API with a coldfusion application. I already setup a connection to the google analytics API with the use of a code written by Jen (https://github.com/jensbits/CF-GA-service/blob/master/cfanalytics/cfanalytics.cfc).

I know this is not a straight forward question, but I am stuck on how to proceed this for google ads. Is there any reference material online that explains how to do this in coldfusion? Or can anyone help with the first steps setting this up.

Comment: My advice would be to make your own api using PHP so you can use the Google Ads PHP SDK. 

If you were to write your own "SDK" in Coldfusion i would expect this to be a very hard task as the SDK's are hard enough to use already.

Plus if you get stuck with a SDK there is a good chance someone can help you.

Comment: @JamesWaring For now I am using the google analytics api to fetch ad costs and clicks. The data available in google analytics is limited and there is no method of changing anything, but it is more then nothing. Php is not available on our servers, it would make more sense to use the Java lib i think.